# Community user does not leave a proper comment when reopening

Tags: feature-request, timeline, reopened-questions

This is a pretty minor detail, but something that may be useful.

When looking at the timeline view of a question that has been closed and reopened it is difficult to tell when the question was reopened.  The Community user leaves a nice comment of **A post was voted to be closed.** on the edit history of the the post when the community votes to close the question, but leaves no edit comment when the question is voted to be reopened.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/966512/timeline)
[Example http://www.imgplace.com/img189/6634/42reopen.png](http://www.imgplace.com/img189/6634/42reopen.png)